# Committing DLL's and Libs to GitHub for Cross-Platform Program

Tags: github, dll, cross-platform

I have a question regarding committing .dll and .lib files for a cross-platform program.  For windows, there are two .lib and .dll files that are needed, but for Ubuntu they are not needed, they just need to install certain packages.

I am using cmake and link the libraries differently depending on the operating system.

Basically my question is if it is bad practice to include the .lib and .dll files in the repository and be downloaded by Ubuntu users and just not used?  How would you handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't commit binary dependencies to a repository.  They tend to bloat the repository and make maintenance operations like `git gc` take much longer than necessary.

Since your tag mentions GitHub, I would just provide the binary dependencies as part of a release asset for your releases.  In other words, if you offer a Windows download in a zip file, just include them in your zip file.  You could also just provide them as a separate release asset if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have some follow up things.  These binaries are precompiled third-party binaries from GLFW and GLEW, not any binaries created during the build process, those aren't committed.  I see what you mean about adding them as release assets after checking our releases, but what if I am no where near a release phase.  Would it be better I just include the source for the libraries and build the binaries as a part of my build process for Windows only?

Comment: If upstream provides binaries, just provide links to download them and SHA-256 hashes for them.  If not, you can just provide a script that downloads the source for the binaries (again, checking them against secure hashes) and builds them, possibly as part of the build process.  You don't need to include the source yourself.

Comment: What is 'upstream'? Can't find anything related online

Comment: _Upstream_ is the original distributor of software.  In this case, the GLFW and GLEW projects.  That's contrasted with _downstream_, who are distributors of other software, like you (or, on Linux, distributions).